# C# dividable with 3(easy)

Tags: math

So I have an assingment. It goes like this. It's a bit more complicated.

The program reads 3 numbers from the user.

IF NONE of these numbers are dividable with 3 OR one of these numbers is dividable with 3, the 3 inputted numbers stay the same.(CASE 1)

IF TWO of these numbers are dividable with 3 THEN the program takes the one with the higher value and adds +1 to it.(CASE 2). BUT IF THESE TWO NUMBERS are EQUAL, then the number that was written second gets +1 added.(CASE 3)

and IF ALL THE NUMBERS are dividable with 3 THEN the second inputetd number gets +1 AND the third inputted number gets added +2.(case 4):

CASE 1: input: 7 9 7
        output: 7 7 7

CASE 2: input: 9 -5 6
        output: 10 -5 6
CASE 3: input: 9 4 9
        output: 9 4 10

CASE 4: input: 9 -6 6
        output: 9 -5 8

THIS IS what I have but it doesn't work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int a, b, c;
        Console.WriteLine("Vnesite prvo stevilo: ");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Vnesite drugo stevilo: ");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Vnesite tretje stevilo: ");
        c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a % 3 != 0 && b % 3 != 0 && c % 3 != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else if (a % 3 == 0 && b % 3 != 0 && c % 3 != 0 || a % 3 != 0 && b % 3 == 0 && c % 3 != 0 || a % 3 != 0 || b % 3 != 0 || c % 3 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else if (a % 3 == 0 && b % 3 == 0 && c % 3 != 0 || a % 3 == 0 && b % 3 != 0 && c % 3 == 0 || a % 3 != 0 && b % 3 == 0 && c % 3 == 0)
        {
            if (a > b)
            {
                a = a + 1;
            }
            else if (b > a)
            {
                b = b + 1;
            }
            else if (b == a) ;
            {
                b = b + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else if (a % 3 == 0 && b % 3 == 0 && c % 3 == 0)
        {
            b = b + 1;
            c = c + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a homework farm

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work".  Doesn't compile?  Do you get an exception?  Wrong output?  Have you run it in the debugger to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Ever consider putting in some brackets there so that operations are done in a specific order? Otherwise, it is subject to interpretation which usually isn't a good thing.

Comment: It doesn't come out as planned. I think there's something wrong either with the || or the &&

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to debug a portion of this code and then think other fixes would be done in a similar manner.Taking a portion of your above code as an example to demonstrate:

```
(a % 3 == 0 && b % 3 != 0 && c % 3 != 0 || a % 3 != 0 && b % 3 == 0 && c % 3 != 0 || a % 3 != 0 || b % 3 != 0 || c % 3 == 0)
```

Assuming this is checking for exactly one of the three to be divisible by 3, I'd likely consider re-writing it this way:

```
((a % 3 == 0 && b % 3 != 0 && c % 3 != 0) || (a % 3 != 0 && b % 3 == 0 && c % 3 != 0) || (a % 3 != 0 && b % 3 != 0 && c % 3 == 0))
```

Note that not only are brackets added so that things are grouped together, but the last group of 3 has the `&&` instead of `||` in it.

The reason for putting in the brackets is that you want things to be evaluated together. The first code line could have an issue where if a is not divisible by 3, the whole expression is short-circuited to be false because a false AND anything will be false, similar to multiplication by 0 will produce 0 in regular Mathematics.

---

This is a portion near the end of what I had initially copied that you had in your logic:

```
|| a % 3 != 0 || b % 3 != 0 || c % 3 == 0)
```

I changed it to this:

```
|| (a % 3 != 0 && b % 3 != 0 && c % 3 == 0))
```

Where I replaced a couple of `||` with `&&` as this part is checking that c is divisible by 3 but a and b are not as one piece.

Comment: I don't know how to use this in practice. I understand but I can't programme it.

Comment: I mean I could if I'd  know how to start.

Comment: Do you see the difference in how the code would work now? Is that enough of a start?

Comment: So basically you added ()?